# Proposing a stochastic model

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, mathematical-modeling, queueing-theory

Successive times between completed handling of requests are described by a distribution with p.d.f.

$$f(x) = \frac{25}{12} e^{-5x/2} + \frac{1}{18}e^{-x/3}$$

It may be assumed that successive interdeparture times of handled requests are independent.

How could one propose a stochastic model for the process of completed requests?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! As it stands, your question is a little too broad. If you provide some more information about what you have tried, and where you get stuck, we can help you better.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not really sure how to approach this problem. It does not seem like any distribution or model that I know of, so any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What you have there is a mixture of two exponential distributions.

Write the density as
$$f(x) = \frac{5}{6}\frac{5}{2}\mathrm e^{-5x/2} + 
\frac{1}{6}\frac{1}{3}\mathrm e^{-x/3}.$$

This describes a random variable that is $Exp(5/2)$ with probability $5/6$, and $Exp(1/3)$ with probability $1/6$.

### Edit after comment

You can model the departure times as a Markov chain. Let $t_n$ be the $n$th departure chain and $\{\Delta_n\}$ be the sequence of interdeparture times -- an iid sequence of random variables with density $f(x)$.

Then, the departure times can be descibed as the Markov chain
$$t_{n+1} = t_n +\Delta_n.$$

Comment: Thanks! Could I then use a Markov chain to model this?

Comment: Yes you can, I've updated my answer.